# read data in panel sliding up panel flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, panel, bottom-sheet, flutter-bottomnavigation

I've used SlidingUpPanel in my main class.
and in the main class, I have a bottom sheet, and then clicking on the bottom sheets icon, load page.
now when I've to use SlidingUpPanel, I have problem loading pages in the body.
can anyone help me with how can I load pages of the bottom navigation in the body of SlidingUpPanel?

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var pageWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SlidingUpPanel(
        controller: _pc,
        panelBuilder: (sc) {
          if (!isCollapsed) _pc.hide();
          return Container(
            child: Center(child: Text("Panel")),
          );
        },

        body: //here I want to load click bottom navigation page
),

bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
 onTap: (index) {
          switch (index) {
            case 0:
              {
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/'); 
                break;
              }
            case 1:
              {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/search');

                break;
              }
            case 2:
              {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/library');
                break;
              }
            case 3:
              {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profile');
                break;
              }
          }
        },           
items[...]   
   ),
    );
  }
```

can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code where you can change the page according to `BottomNavigationBar` item clicks

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

      final String title;

      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final widgets = [
        Container(color: Colors.red),
        Container(color: Colors.green),
        Container(color: Colors.yellow),
      ];
      int currentIndex = 0;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: SlidingUpPanel(
            panel: Center(
              child: Text("This is the sliding Widget"),
            ),
            body: widgets[currentIndex],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: 'Settings'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'About'),
            ],
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                currentIndex = index;
              });
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: and how can i call something like this -> `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');` in list of widgets? i have a class for routs             `Map<String, WidgetBuilder> routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  '/': (context) => const ExplorePage(),
  '/search': (context) => const SearchPage(),
  '/library': (context) => const LibraryPage(),
  '/profile': (context) => const ProfilePage(),
};`

Comment: routes are different than widgets. by using routes you can navigate to different pages in widgets above example you can replace them.

Comment: ok, how can I call classes in the widgets? `ExplorePage(),
SearchPage(),
 LibraryPage(),
 ProfilePage(),`

Comment: final widgets = [
    ExplorePage(),
    SearchPage(),
    LibraryPage(),
    ProfilePage(),
  ];

Comment: I do this. but not work and scroll in the compiler.

Comment: I have explained how to achieve it but you have to fix your other problems. If scroll is not happening wrap SingleChildScrollView